# Fedora installation failed due to corrupt downloading — what can I do?

Tags: installation, fedora

I have downloaded Fedora 15 & burned the image file to a DVD, but during installation it failed and informed me that `vlgothik` font package installation failed. It may be due to corrupt downloading.

Now what should I do to complete the installation?

Answer (score 1):

You need to download the ISO again. After download you'll need to do an md5 check. For future reference, it may help people helping you if you specify what operating system you are currently using and give a more specific title to the request.